# может быть a могу

Tags: выбор-слова

I hear both as "I can", but when is it appropriate to use either or?

I am aware the former means "maybe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that могу is a verb, and можно is an adverb. If you confused about the meaning or using these words in practice: могу is more like when you say 'I can' (do something or expressing a state about yourself depending on context, etc), e.g. я могу быть сильным/I can be strong. можно is usually used in the questions or when you are asking for an allowance to do something e.g. можно мне войти?/can I come in? However, in Russian language we also use могу in questions, e.g/. могу я войти?/can I come in? Thus, могу and можно in questions will mean the same

Может быть can be also used as “maybe”

Examples:

Может быть, Вы правы

Maybe you're right.

Может быть дождь до вечера.

It might** rain before evening

Может быть, в этом и есть доля правды

There *may be* some truth to this

Могу used as Can I/May I:

Могу ли я начать?

Can I begin?

Могу ли я включить свет?

May I switch on the light?

Comment: you're* maybe right. think "you are"

Answer (score 1):

In the Russian verb phrase there are two modals: 
one of possibility and the other of ability.

So the English equivalent must be:

I **may** (or **might**) **be** **able** to do...